# Take the derivative of a lambda function in Python

Tags: python, derivative

If I have a lambda function such as:

```
f = lambda x : x**2
```

*Which does not call any Python C extensions*

How can I automatically create another lambda function *f1* that **represents** the first derivative of the original `f` function?

```
f1 = lambda x : 2*x
```

Also, I would like to be able to calculate the *nth* derivative from it.

I have tried to use `sympy` and `mpmath` modules without optimal results. In addition, creating a custom function that approximates the value of the derivative at a point and perform a recursive call to the function to get the *nth* derivative seems very inefficient on large `n` values.

The ultimate goal is to find a way of taking a `lambda` function `f` and return another `lambda` function `f1`, which is the derivative of the original one. Also, it would be appreciated if the method works for the second, third... derivatives of the `f` input lambda function.

Comment: Have you looked into automatic differentiation and tools like autograd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use the basic formula of a derivative, `Δy/Δx` with `Δx` as small as possible, for this. Although it is not 100% accurate, it can be used on every lambda function without knowing its syntax or the sort of the function.

Here's a python implementation:

```py
f=lambda x:x**2
import sys
deltax=sys.float_info.epsilon*(2**11)
def derivative(f,x):
    y1=f(x-deltax/2)
    y2=f(x+deltax/2)
    return (y2-y1)/deltax
print(derivative(f,1))
```

If it stops working correctly or becomes inaccurate with higher values, you can always increase the 11 on the second line to a higher number. Note that this might lead to innacurate result with lower numbers.

Here's also a variant with higher order derivatives, but it seems to be very much changing when adapting the above. A value of 36 gave me the best results.

```py
def derivative(f,x,order=1):
    if order>1:
        y1=derivative(f,x-deltax/2,order-1)
        y2=derivative(f,x+deltax/2,order-1)
    else:
        y1=f(x-deltax/2)
        y2=f(x+deltax/2)
    return (y2-y1)/deltax
```

Comment: What about `derivative(eval,'0')` ? And `f` means two things in your example (a variable, and a formal argument to `derivative`)

Comment: What does that have to do with lambda functions, as in the question? I assume that the questioner will only use normal lambda functions, returning and accepting int or float values. Something like this should be passed in as `lambda x : eval(str(x))`

Comment: I coded a very similar solution and found it a bit inefficient. Then I posted this question hoping to get an optimal solution but seeing the rest of the answers and the number of downvotes *usual*, I think I'm not going to get anything more efficient than this. Thanks for your answer

Comment: And what is the derivative of `lambda x : eval(str(x))` (e.g. near 0) ? Or of `lambda x: return  gc.get_stats()` ?

Comment: `lambda x : eval(str(x))` is the same as the identity function, `lamdda x: x`, and thus its derivative is always 1. I don't see any way to get the derivative of such a function as `lambda x: return  gc.get_stats()`, and as such it is not included in the answer.

Comment: I don't think that the questioner wants to find the derivative of such complex functions. I think that he wants to find the derivative of normal, mathematical functions depending on no other thing than the input value. As such, and because other functions have no obvious derivative, I don't include them in the answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "And `f` means two things in your example (a variable, and a formal argument to `derivative`)" - What is the problem with that? As both variables are in different scopes, they won't interfere with eachother. There's also no confusion possible, as they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general solution for this problem, because not every function has a derivative.
For example there is no way to find the derivative of functions like:

```
f = lambda x: random()
g = lambda x: str(x)
```

You could define classes for some types of differentiable functions, like constant functions, polynomial functions, sums of other differentiable functions, etc., for example:

```
class ConstantFunction:
    def __init__(self, constant):
        self.constant = constant
    
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.constant
    
    def derivative(self):
        return ConstantFunction(0)

f = ConstantFunction(10)
print(f(3))
f1 = f.derivative()
print(f1(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to **access the abstract syntax tree** of your `f` function. Use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

You then want to implement or reuse some symbolic computation.

You could (if required) have a sequence (or some set) of [rewrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) rules in your program (rewriting abstract syntax tree and implementing some kind of [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))).

Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and of the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Some functions are not derivable (e.g. at 0:  `lambda x : x**2 * sin(1/x)` ...)

Other functions are not returning numbers. E.g. [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) ...

What should be the derivative of `lambda s : eval (s + "+" + s)` (we expect `s` to be some string since [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) requires one)? Or (on Linux) a Python function parsing `/proc/self/maps` (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) or `/dev/random` (see [random(4)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)) or counting the number of lines inside it?

NB. I guess you want symbolic processing. For numerical processing things are different (maybe use TensorFlow? Or find a Python binding to [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)? What about [custom Python extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) coded in C).
What about lambda functions calling operating system primitives like [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) or [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) (or [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) programs)

Comment: @Cardstani: I don't understand what is your actual task. Could you edit your question to add a hundred words of English about it....

Comment: The goal is to find a way to take a lambda function f and get another lambda function f1 which is the derivative of the original `f`. @basile-starynkevitch

Comment: Please *edit your question*. What if the lambda function is calling some custom [Python C extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)?

Comment: The lambda function will **NEVER** call Python C extensions. If you look at the example from the question, it's just a normal lambda function.

Comment: That should go in your question, not in  a comment

Comment: As you can see in the **`question`**, I want to output a lambda function that is the formal representation of the original one. So I don't care if it's not derivable at values like 0 @basile-starynkevitch